# Loading GeoJSON from local server to show by OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson, tomcat

I've written some code to create a vector layer based on a GeoJSON file located on my computer. I've deployed the tomcat server and put my GeoJSON file in some path like:

> webapps/OpenLayersAsset/countries.geojson

Next using the following code to show the file but I get the error "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/OpenLayersAssets/countries.geojson". Does it cause the byGeoJSON location or something else?

```
var countrySource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/OpenLayersAssets/countries.geojson',
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
var countryLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: countrySource
});

var center = ol.proj.transform([51.34, 35.65], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
var view = new ol.View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 8
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [countryLayer],
    view: view
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have found the "Cross domain" error, you are requesting resources from different base URLs. The browser imposes the *same origin policy*.

The port counts (using 8080 makes its a different URL). So, if you request things from `http://localhost/ol3.js` and from `http://localhost:8080/OpenLayersAssets/countries.geojson` you will end up with the "Cross domain" error.

To prevent *same origin policy* protecting, you can:

- Make sure you serve all your resources from the same base URL, like `http://localhost:8080/...`
- Use a proxy and request all external resources using the proxy (it is more complicated)
- Configure tomcat to allow CORS requests. Edit the `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml` file to add another filter, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363192/cors-tomcat-geoserver/25025579

Comment: Thanks, jgrocha. I chose the third option as it was explained.Also I had added the "cors-filter" for another we.xml file related to Geoserver before but it differs. Thanks again!